# How may I change the form authetication to allow the users to access an aspx page if they were POSTed or redirected to it?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, form-authentication

I have used these codes in my web.config file:

```
  <location path="Code.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I know it does not allow the users to access the Code.aspx page. How may I change it to allow the users to access the page, if they were POSTed or redirected to the Code.aspx page?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this? If this is a security measure that you are trying to achieve then please don't do that.

Comment: I have a web page which contains a button, after clicking the button, it will be redirected to another webpage to pay online (another website) and finally it posted to the last page which shows a code. I don't know how to make this secure because I think it could be hacked easily. I think if I could do what I have said, it could be secure.

Comment: So when user clicks a button on first page, you can set a Session variable, and redirect it to page B on different site. When the user returns from page B to page C, in Page_Load check for the session variable value that you set in Page A and some posted result from page B. Then validate everything and if something doesn't look right (e.g. Session variable is not in place) instead of processing the request redirect the user to page A.

Comment: I have used this, But it is not so secure. It could be hacked in a way.

Comment: What way are you talking about? The only way to make the specific page secure is to rely on the state that user cannot easily spoof. Session is one of these states. It is quite easy so POST instead of get, referrer site can be changed as well

Comment: If the user click on the button, the session will be saved.Now if he did not, he could open the secound page by pasting the url and add the query string if necessary, then everything will be available.

Comment: So if you want to verify that the user actually paid, you need to verify the response from payment provider. I doubt that there is a payment provider which does not give you a response with some kind of signature that you can verify. If you actually are using such provider then try looking for alternatives

Comment: Perhaps I don't know how to verify it. I want to use PerfectMoney API. But I don't know how to verify if the user prepaid it or not.

Comment: So your initial question is actually not what you need. You should read PerfectMoney API documentation and I'm certain there will be an information on how to verify if the payment was successful or not. Good luck!

Comment: I read that but I think I don't know how to verify because it's my first experience. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to allow all users `<allow users ="*" />` and then do your corresponding checks in the codebehind of code.aspx. Here you can verify if the user was posted to the page or if he got redirected from a allowed source page.

Comment: Is there any web link which could help me? I have used Session but I know it could be hacked in a way.

Comment: First of all, from that what I read in your comments you should not allow all users. The user still needs to be authenticated to visit your code.aspx. However, you can check `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` to check if the user comes from the trusted source. But this alone is not secure because it can be tempered on the client side. What I recommend is, that you create a token on your page, that is posting to code.aspx. On code.aspx you can validate the token and ensure, that the user can be trusted

Comment: I don't know how to create a tocken.